# How do I use expr in a for loop?

Tags: shell, for-loop

I am new to scripting and I need to write a script for my class using a for loop. The script should allow you to type numbers at the command line prompt and then it will sum them and give you the answer. I keep getting an expr: syntax error and I also think I have a problem with the in part of the for loop.

```
echo 'Please enter some numbers:'
read ;
for i in echo $read ;
do expr + 
done
```

I know there are a lot of mistakes, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What do you expect the "expr" to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]
then
  echo 'sum.sh [numbers]'
  exit
fi

for number
do
  let total+=number
done
echo $total
```

Example:

```
$ sum.sh
sum.sh [numbers]

$ sum.sh 2
2

$ sum.sh 2 2 3
7
```

Comment: +1 really like the brevity of input test *or* usage. I'm going to put that in my bag o' tricks

Comment: @Bohemian: It's nice, but not really robust.  Try `sum.sh -f`, for example.  Robustness suggests `[ $# -gt 0 ] || usage` (check whether the number of positional parameters is greater than zero; if not, report on the correct usage).  Also, it is courteous to use a message such as: `echo "Usage: $(basename $0 .sh) number [...]" >&2; exit 1` which reports the usage in a standard format to standard error. The `exit 1` means that you can tell that the script was misused by its exit status. (I'd put the statements on two lines in a script; the semicolon is for accuracy in a comment — no formatting!)

Comment: What would I put for the "in" part of the for loop? Don't I have to put something so it will take the input from the prompt? I am new at this so it is kind of confusing.

Comment: @JillianRoberts if you leave off the `in` part, it takes from the positional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`expr` needs the numbers with space-separated plusses between them in order to do anything.

```
read one another
expr "$one" + "$another"
```

At this point, I expect your professor wants you to discover how to loop over one input at a time, and run `expr` to add to the sum you have accumulated during previous iterations of the loop.

For anything real-world, you're probably better off using `dc` or `bc`, or, heck, Awk or a proper scripting language.

Comment: If you need floating point, then `bc`, but for integer arithmetic, `bash` and other POSIX shells have `$((...))` which is quite powerful, and also `((...))` which is closely related and originated with the Korn shell, but is not POSIX-standard. (I've not spent the time working out when to use the `((...))` and when to use `$((...))`.)

Comment: The ((...)) syntax and $((...)) is not POSIX so I find that detail in your comment slightly misleading. But yeah, if Bash is available and allowed, then do use that instead.

Comment: The `$((...))` notation is in POSIX shell — see [Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) in POSIX 2008 and [Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_006_004) in the Single Unix Specification v2 from 1997.  The `((...))` notation is not POSIX and I said as much.

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected; `$((...))` is indeed defined in POSIX shell.